# Use the same calculation n number of times

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following three inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="cost" id="cost"  oninput="calculate()" value="">
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" oninput="calculate()" value="">
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="" readonly >
```

When the price and quantity are entered the following function calculates the total:

```
function calculate() {
    var price = document.getElementById('cost').value;  
    var num = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
    var total1 = document.getElementById('total');  
    var myResult = price * num;
    total.value = myResult;
}
```

The three inputs can be repeated an unknown number of times depending on the number of entry's in a database table. I would like to use the same function on all the inputs, but despite searching for hours, I'm no further forward. I believe I will need to use getElementsByName. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group your inputs together. So given one input, you can easily find the other inputs. Then use `calculate(this)` instead of `calculate()`. `this` in this case refers to the input that was changed.

```js
function calculate(e) {
  var div = e.parentNode;
  var c = div.querySelector('.cost').value;
  var q = div.querySelector('.quantity').value;
  div.querySelector('.total').value = c * q;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="cost" oninput="calculate(this)" value="">
  <input type="text" class="quantity" oninput="calculate(this)" value="">
  <input type="text" class="total" value="" readonly>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="cost" oninput="calculate(this)" value="">
  <input type="text" class="quantity" oninput="calculate(this)" value="">
  <input type="text" class="total" value="" readonly>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="cost" oninput="calculate(this)" value="">
  <input type="text" class="quantity" oninput="calculate(this)" value="">
  <input type="text" class="total" value="" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Fabricator, what an elegantly simple solution!

Answer (score 3):

### Use getElementsByClassName()

Use same class name for the repeating inputs and access them using document.getElementsByClassName() function as following:

```
function calculate() {
 var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('cost').length;
 for(i=0; i< classes; i++)
 {
    var price = document.getElementsByClassName('cost')[i].value;  
    var num = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity')[i].value;

    var myResult = price * num;
    document.getElementsByClassName('total')[i].value = myResult;
 }

}
```

and your html

```
  <h2>Group 1:</h2>

<input type="text" name="cost" class="cost" id="cost1"  oninput="calculate()" value="">
<input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" id="quantity1" oninput="calculate()" value="">
<input type="text" name="total" class="total" id="total1" value="" readonly >

  <h2>Group 2:</h2>

<input type="text" name="cost" class="cost" id="cost2"  oninput="calculate()" value="">
<input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" id="quantity2" oninput="calculate()" value="">
<input type="text" name="total" class="total" id="total2" value="" readonly >

  <h2>Group 3:</h2>

<input type="text" name="cost" class="cost" id="cost3"  oninput="calculate()" value="">
<input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" id="quantity3" oninput="calculate()" value="">
<input type="text" name="total" class="total" id="total3" value="" readonly >
```

**See Demo: http://jsbin.com/kabuduzozo/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: +1 and a comment, elements IDs **should** be unique, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme

Comment: It's a pretty bad approach. `calculate` should not recalculate totals for all the fields, this is not necessary. Plus requerying the DOM for every change. @Fabricator provided decent solution.

Comment: Agree, @Fabricator is more elegant and lean approach, I gave him +1.

Comment: Thanks you Shadi, that was sort of what I thought but couldn't get to.